# .htaccess rewrite url for pages only, not directories

Tags: .htaccess

right now I have some htaccess rules to rewrite my url from example.com?node=home to example.com/home and example.com?node=gallery&id=56 to exmaple.com/gallery/56. Also it fixes my directory paths for my links, css stylesheet, photos and such for the webpage itself are linked correctly, now all of this works as it should, the problem I'm having is if I try to access say, example.com/filename.jpg, it thinks that filename.jpg is a page that it should try to load, instead of bringing me to the directory. So how come this is so, and how can I fix this, and still have my htaccess rules work as they should?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php/?node=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php/?node=$1 [L,QSA]
```

now I also have on the index.php page:

```
<base href="http://www.mysite.com">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php/?node=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]

## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php/?node=$1 [L,QSA]
```